# Jquery Ajax Code to populate DropDown Dynamically and resting select

Tags: jquery

I want to populate Drop Down Dynamically Using json. I need Suggestion of populating dynamically. Is it good way to use on Click? As i have Large Number of records

```
function getKitNames(id)
{

    kitName=new Array();

    $.post("/EBioData/AddRowDetailsServlet", {
        type:'kitName'
    }, function(data) {
        var json = eval('(' + data +')')

        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){

            $("#kitName"+id).append('<option value='
                +json[i]['kitName']+' >'+json[i]['kitName']
                +'</option>');

        }
    //        
    });
}
```

Here is my select in Javascript ccode which is added dynamically
kitRowCount=1

```
<select id="kitName1" name="kitName" 
      onChange="return getKitMake(this.value,1);"  onclick=getKitName(1)>
    <option value=select >select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this code: `eval('(' + data +')')` is not going to evaluate to a JSON object.

Comment: this code: `kitName=new Array();` declares a global object, did you mean to do that?  You do not seem to be using it...

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should populate as soon as the page has loaded and while it's not yet populated replace the content with a loading element.
You also should use JSON.parse instead of eval.

If you do it on click you have to ensure it's only loaded once (same with in page navigation, if you have a lot of element considere caching).
Maybe you need dynamic refresh on each click?